# mysql crash on Docker/Ubuntu/Windows

Tags: mysql, docker

mysql crash often

Since the last docker upgrade, I get serious problems with mysql, and need to constantly recreate my docker container

sometime I can solve it by resetarting my container.

I don't see much info in the mysql log:

```
2020-04-28T21:03:06.300739Z 0 [Note] Recovering after a crash using ON
2020-04-28T21:03:06.300803Z 0 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
2020-04-28T21:03:06.300926Z 0 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
2020-04-28T21:03:06.328418Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2020-04-28T21:03:06.328479Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2020-04-28T21:03:06.329025Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-04-28T21:03:06.329073Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2020-04-28T21:03:06.329313Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
2020-04-28T21:03:06.329365Z 0 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
2020-04-28T21:03:06.329412Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2020-04-28T21:03:06.335031Z 0 [Note] Failed to start slave threads for channel ''
2020-04-28T21:03:06.341146Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2020-04-28T21:03:06.341437Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-log'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
2020-04-28T21:03:06.614926Z 2 [Note] Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2020-04-28T21:03:06.638009Z 3 [Note] Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

docker

```
docker -v
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  ba:
    image: mattrayner/lamp:latest-1804
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.3:80:80'
      - '127.0.0.3:8080:8080'
    volumes: ['./:/app']
```

I tried different images, but the problem persists, it started happen only after the latest docker upgrade.

Any help will be appreciated,

Attached is the docker log:

```js
Updating for 7.4
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown command: `u'
=> Using an existing volume of MySQL
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:298: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2020-05-04 08:18:59,646 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2020-05-04 08:18:59,646 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord-apache2.conf" during parsing
2020-05-04 08:18:59,647 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord-mysqld.conf" during parsing
2020-05-04 08:18:59,656 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2020-05-04 08:18:59,656 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2020-05-04 08:18:59,656 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2020-05-04 08:19:00,659 INFO spawned: 'mysqld' with pid 1562
2020-05-04 08:19:00,660 INFO spawned: 'apache2' with pid 1563
2020-05-04 08:19:00,704 INFO exited: apache2 (exit status 0; not expected)
2020-05-04 08:19:00,876 INFO exited: mysqld (exit status 1; not expected)
2020-05-04 08:19:01,878 INFO spawned: 'mysqld' with pid 1959
2020-05-04 08:19:01,880 INFO spawned: 'apache2' with pid 1960
2020-05-04 08:19:01,938 INFO exited: apache2 (exit status 0; not expected)
2020-05-04 08:19:02,161 INFO exited: mysqld (exit status 1; not expected)
2020-05-04 08:19:04,165 INFO spawned: 'mysqld' with pid 2366
2020-05-04 08:19:04,166 INFO spawned: 'apache2' with pid 2369
```

Comment: Have you checked docker logs? `docker logs -f <container_id>`

Comment: @Shiva 10x for your comment, I added the logs

Comment: See if this is helpful - https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213361889-Unable-to-start-MySQL-Access-denied-for-user-debian-sys-maint-localhost-using-password-YES-. The image itself could be buggy, you can raise an issue at https://github.com/mattrayner/docker-lamp/issues

Comment: 10x, I will check, it happens with 3 different images, I believe it is related to docker upgrade, I will try to downgrade if I cannot by pass it somehow

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I have the same issue on Windows.